# When did self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets start adjusting inset?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I noticed that inset has not been changed in viewDidLoad

However it has been changed in -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

So things are changed somewhere between.

It's for UIViewController class

When?